# my code stops running after '.get' (webdriver) an url and download the in-page pdf

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, firefox

I have a list with many urls, each of these urls contains a pdf which I want to download. I give you two of them to provide you anything to try with:

https://api.fundinfo.com/document/7cce253b158e363bbb16114aef68e603_107896/KID_ES_es_ES0115114003_YES_2015-09-18.pdf?apiKey=509a6b5360d1d850ae303d8af3652c37

https://api.fundinfo.com/document/bbc2aab2a5273e44d5b002946ea86071_901674/AR_ES_es_ES0156873004_YES_2014-12-31.pdf?apiKey=509a6b5360d1d850ae303d8af3652c37

I'm using selenium with firefox to do this, and I¨'ve tried it of several ways. At first I entered the page and clicked the download button of each pdf. However after a while the firefox stops and close because of the overload, even with time.sleep(1-2 seconds) it appears to break.

So I selected in the settings of firefox to just download the file when the url is charged (just writting the url, and the file starts to download). Then I import the firefox profile with webdriver to have this configuration, and so lighten the work of firefox in the looping.

This is my CODE now:

```
 from selenium import webdriver

 from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import FirefoxProfile

 profile = FirefoxProfile('C:/Users/xe64570/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/bya1fhim.default')
 browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
 for i in urls:
      browser.get(i)
```

PROBLEM:

After executing the first `browser.get(i)` the first pdf is downloaded, but the script stops without any error, like 'still waiting'. I say waiting because it seems like if the page didn't get charged in the eyes of the webdriver. The first file is just got but nothing happens in the browser, so it seems 'to continue thinking' that the page hasn't been charged yet, and it has to wait until it happens. And so it remains stuck.

How could avoid this??

Thank you very much

Comment: I'm not sure why this happens, but you can get these pdfs with `requests` and not jump out to a browser at all.

Comment: If you are so kind, could you give an example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These urls can be downloaded without browser help, so you can avoid the selenium complication completely. Here's an example that could use a bit more exception handling but works for grabbing these urls.

```
import requests
import multiprocessing.pool
import contextlib

# randomly choosing max parallel downloads...
PARALLEL_DOWNLOADS = 4

def download_pdf(url):
    with contextlib.closing(requests.get(url, stream=True)) as resp:
        if resp.status_code//100 != 2:
            return "failed {}".format(reps.status_code)
        if resp.headers['Content-Type'] != 'application/pdf':
            return "not a pdf"
        # this app returns pdf name in content-disposition
        disp = resp.headers['Content-Disposition']
        if 'filename=' in disp:
            filename = disp.split('=')[1].strip().strip('"')
        else:
            return "unknown filename"
        print("downloading", filename, "...")
        with open(filename, 'wb') as fp:
            for chunk in resp.iter_content():
                fp.write(chunk)
        return filename

urls = ["https://api.fundinfo.com/document/7cce253b158e363bbb16114aef68e603_107896/KID_ES_es_ES0115114003_YES_2015-09-18.pdf?apiKey=509a6b5360d1d850ae303d8af3652c37",
"https://api.fundinfo.com/document/bbc2aab2a5273e44d5b002946ea86071_901674/AR_ES_es_ES0156873004_YES_2014-12-31.pdf?apiKey=509a6b5360d1d850ae303d8af3652c37"
]

if __name__=="__main__":
    pool = multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(min(len(urls), PARALLEL_DOWNLOADS))
    for result in pool.map(download_pdf, urls, chunksize=1):
        print(result)
    pool.close()
```

Comment: I have another question about this issue: Why is necessary here the magic variable `__name__`?

Comment: It makes sure the code is only run when this is a top level script, not when its imported by another module. It doesn't matter in this example, but you could change to a process pool (`multiprocessing.Pool`) and then it would be needed on Windows. This code is I/O bound so thread pool is fine.

Comment: I understand more or less, I will read a bit about threading...
I have another problem, I've realised that the files are being written bad (corrupted). I suppose there should be something wrong in the write process. What do you think?

Comment: The two example urls you posted download okay for me. If you can post one that fails, I can try it.

Comment: Sorry, my fail... I introduced an order where I shoudnt't have done it and I didn't realise! Thanks again!